# How to use grids/Tables in LWUIT?

Tags: lwuit

How to use grids/Tables in LWUIT?

Comment: Are you talking about data grids/tables or user interface layout?

Answer (score 3):

The grid layout object is com.sun.lwuit.layouts.GridLayout -- say you make:

```
GridLayout myGrid = new GridLayout(numrows, numcolumns);
```

with the number of rows and columns you want, then you make a container (i.e. a com.sun.lwuit.Container) like:

```
Container myTable = new Container(myGrid);
```

and then you work with `myTable` as you would with any other `Container` as per the [docs](https://lwuit.dev.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/Container.html), i.e., by calling `myTable.addComponent` with the components you want to put in the grid/table, `myTable.getComponentIndex` to find the index corresponding to a component you've added, `myTable.getComponent` to retrieve a component from its index, `.removeComponent` to take a component away, `removeAll` to empty the whole table, `replace` to change one component into another via a transition, etc, etc.

Don't be misled by the two-arguments form of `getComponent`: like for any other container, the two arguments are pixel coordinates, NOT row and col indices -- to retrieve a component by row and col you'll instead be using the single-argument form (indexing starts on the top left and proceeds rightwards, then downwards).

Answer (score 1):

Now you can do too:

```
  TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
            new String[] {"Date", "Detail", "$"},
            new Object[][] {
              {"21/03/2010", "aaa", "$ -102"},
              {"18/03/2010", "bbb", "$ -230"},
              {"23/03/2010", "ccc", "$ 500"},
              {"Saldo Actual", "", "$ 2.520"},
            });

    Table mytable = new Table(model);
```